# handling different gestures on different UIViews in same point

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have two views in the same location on screen.

The top view should handle pan gesture and the bottom should handle `TouchUpInside`.

I'm only getting the panning gesture event and not the `TouchUpInside` event.

I read about [Hit-testing](http://smnh.me/hit-testing-in-ios/) so i understand what is happening but is there a way to make the event pass to both the views?

Thanks